Post Request failing on blinks action
I am following the recently published solana-bootcamp-24. Facing error while trying interacting with the blink by voting.
575-d832fb2fecfcad8d.js:14 GOT ERROR Gt: Unexpected error
    at Ml.#o (chrome-extension://bfnaelmomeimhlpmgjnjophhpkkoljpa/solana.js:3:231648)
    at async Ml.signAndSendTransaction (chrome-extension://bfnaelmomeimhlpmgjnjophhpkkoljpa/solana.js:3:233781)
    at async #d [as signAndSendTransaction] (chrome-extension://bfnaelmomeimhlpmgjnjophhpkkoljpa/solana.js:3:238718)
    at async tb.sendTransaction (https://dial.to/_next/static/chunks/661-22ea009ee6623342.js:1:125602)
    at async Object.sendTransaction (https://dial.to/_next/static/chunks/661-22ea009ee6623342.js:1:133446)
    at async Object.signTransaction (https://dial.to/_next/static/chunks/400-d171f1a852b43fa4.js:8:16633)
    at async M (https://dial.to/_next/static/chunks/485-14d15fe20bc5877a.js:11:7592)
    at async onClick (https://dial.to/_next/static/chunks/485-14d15fe20bc5877a.js:13:8365)

575-d832fb2fecfcad8d.js:14 WalletSendTransactionError: Unexpected error
    at tb.sendTransaction (661-22ea009ee6623342.js:1:126245)
    at async Object.sendTransaction (661-22ea009ee6623342.js:1:133446)
    at async Object.signTransaction (400-d171f1a852b43fa4.js:8:16633)
    at async M (485-14d15fe20bc5877a.js:11:7592)
    at async onClick (485-14d15fe20bc5877a.js:13:8365) tb {_events: r, _eventsCount: 4, signIn: ƒ, signTransaction: ƒ, signAllTransactions: ƒ, …}

code:
export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {

  const candidate = new URL(request.url).searchParams.get("candidate");
  console.log("candidate: " + candidate)

  if (candidate != "PanMan" && candidate != "CanWoman") {
    return new NextResponse("Invalid candidate", { status: 400, headers: ACTIONS_CORS_HEADERS });
  }

  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("testnet"), "confirmed")
  const program: Program<Voting> = new Program(IDL, { connection })
  const body: ActionPostRequest = await request.json()
  let voter;

  try {
    voter = new PublicKey(body.account)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("cant fetch account")
    return new NextResponse("invalid account", { status: 400, headers: ACTIONS_CORS_HEADERS })
  }

  const instruction = await program.methods
    .vote(new BN(1), candidate)
    .accounts({
      signer: voter,
    })
    .instruction()

  const blockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash()

  const transaction = new Transaction({
    feePayer: voter,
    blockhash: blockhash.blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: blockhash.lastValidBlockHeight
  }).add(instruction)

  const response = await createPostResponse({
    fields: {
      type: "transaction",
      transaction
    }
  })

  return NextResponse.json(response, { status: 200, headers: ACTIONS_CORS_HEADERS })
}


I did initialized polls and candidates by running bankrun tests
modified provider to anchor.AnchorProvider.env()
The programId are not mismatched

